# Angular 2 dynamic form get complex values

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have implemented dynamic forms in angular based on their Dynamic forms cookbook [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html). My inputs have id attributes as well. How do I process the form when it is submitted? The tutorial suggests doing:

> his.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);

but that only gets me the values with no metadata about them.
The form object contains controls array with my inputs, but the values aren't there.

My input:

```
<input [formControlName]="input.key" [id]="input.key" [type]="input.type" class="form-control">
```

I would like to be able to access the value of the input, so that it looks similar to this:

```
form: [
    {   
        id: 'id of the input',
        value: 'value of the input'
    },
    ...
```

I found a way how to this but it requires looking through the Controls of the Form after I get the data and that is wrong and unnecessary. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in FormGroup's value property.

In your case:

```
 this.form.value = ...
```

Form's value depends on Control Value Accessor of every single control in form. So, you need to implement your own ControlValueAcessor to use in your form's control. It's not that hard and there is a really good tutorial:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html. Check it out. 
In your implementation you should get the id and value and merge them in one object, then make this merged object the object's value.

Direct link to tutorial's plunker: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html#demos.

Comment: I was able to implement it, the struggle was understanding the binding with formControlValue.